# How to find Subspaces of M2x2

Tags: linear-algebra

Preparing for an exam and came across this question. My general understanding of M2x2 matrice isnt that great so it would be good if someone answers this

Which of the following are subspaces of M2,2? Be sure to justify your answer in each case
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zsxAY.png)

Comment: Do you know the axioms of a vector space and definition of a subspace? Can you prove that option (a) is the answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For a, note that the zero matrix definitely satisfies our condition, scalar multiplication is easy to see, and addition follows from the fact that 
$$
a=b,\;\text{and}\;x=y\implies a+x=b+y
$$

For completeness, b fails all three conditions.

c fails by noting that 
$$
\begin{bmatrix} 1&0\\0&0\end{bmatrix}+\begin{bmatrix} 0&0\\0&1\end{bmatrix}
$$
has determinant $1$.

d fails by taking $A$ with $A^2=A$ and noting that 
$$
(5A)^2=25A^2=25A\ne5A
$$

Answer (score 0):

Take case (c). All you need to do is take two $2\times 2$ matrices e.g. $
   A=
  \left[ {\begin{array}{cc}
   1 & 0 \\
   0 & 0 \\
  \end{array} } \right]
$
and $
   B=
  \left[ {\begin{array}{cc}
   0 & 0 \\
   0 & 1 \\
  \end{array} } \right]
$
both of these have $0$ determinant. Now what about $A+B$?